# Python run socket at startup and the rest of the program when i want

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, startup

Can you help me? I have a problem with my python project I have to start a socket that listens as a server at startup but then when I want I have to be able to connect to administer the server how can I create a socket that starts at startup and be able to interact with the program when I want??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I Just want to Say of there's a methot to start a socket.bind at startup and the actual interactive program after

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).